# How do I make bootstrap card the entire height of the component?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, image

I want my login screen to be a card the size of the entire screen with a background image and overlay. When I adjust the browser size, I can see whitespace below the image. I would like the image to adjust to the browser size.

```
<div class="card text-white">
    <img class="card-img" src="../../../assets/login-image/home.jpg">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <div class="display-4 title">Acqusitions</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div>
                <h2 class="card-title">Login</h2>
                <div class="forms">
                  <div class="card-text input-group input-group-lg username">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username">
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-text input-group input-group-lg password">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center buttonPad">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="loginUser(username, password)">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="loginError" class="padTop" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    {{errMessage}}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.card {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

also make sure you have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-heigth, initial-scale=1">` set, in order for your browser to get the viewport sizes and apply that to the content. You could also add a base 100vh to the `body` (use a class instead of using the html tag to add styles), and then use height: 100% when needed.

The problem with relying too much on bootstrap (specially if you are new) is that css rules become confusing (because the style mindset of bootstrap is different than that of css). I would suggest you try to do some boostrap-included-classes stuff yourself (manually), and then use bootstrap as a time-saver instead of using it because it's easier. You have to know what it does and how.

I personally don't like bootstrap because some things can't be overriden without using '!important' which is horrible, or eliminating the encapsulation, but that's personal and off-topic. Hope it helps!